# java - "XX" is already defined

Tags: java, string, defined

```
private String createOrderSummary(String orderPersonName, int quantity, int price) {
    String orderPersonName = "Kaptain Kunal";
    String createOrderSummary = "Name: " + orderPersonName;
    createOrderSummary = createOrderSummary + "\nQuantity: " + quantity;
    createOrderSummary = createOrderSummary + "\nTotal: " + price;
    createOrderSummary = createOrderSummary + "\nThank you!";
    return createOrderSummary;
}
```

It says "orderPersonName" is already defined. I see 2 times above, but I don't get it because isn't first one "defining" and second one "utilizing"?

Could you explain?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is already defined in the head of the function; you cannot create the same variable again; just replace

```
String orderPersonName = "Kaptain Kunal";
```

with

```
orderPersonName = "Kaptain Kunal";
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know that "private String createOrderSummary(String orderPersonName, int quantity, int price) " the first line defines "orderPersonName" as "String" already. This helped :)

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues here. The first is that you have a parameter with the same name as a local variable. If you just take out the redeclaration but leave in the assignment to `orderPersonName` as suggested elsewhere, your code will compile and run, but you will still have the second problem - you will be overriding your method's copy of (and therefore losing access to) the value that's passed to the method, which is probably not what you want to do. For example, if I call your method with:

```
createOrderSummary("Cupán Tae", 1, 100);
```

It will return a String beginning `Name: Kaptain Kunal`, which doesn't make sense.

Most likely you just want to remove the entire `String orderPersonName = "Kaptain Kunal";` and instead pass the string into the method, e.g.:

```
createOrderSummary("Kaptain Kunal", 1, 100);
```

Also, to avoid accidentally introducing this second problem, you should consider making your parameters `final` - then the compiler won't allow you to reassign them inside the method.

```
private String createOrderSummary(final String orderPersonName, final int quantity, final int price)
```

Comment: Whatever you do, an assignment to any parameter has no effect except locally within the method. Java passes parameters by reference, String is an Object, and the assignment changes the local copy of the reference, not the original reference.

Comment: True - I didn't mean to imply otherwise. Always a balance between brevity/clarity and getting in as much useful information as possible. Added a slight clarification, thanks